# Primitive Shapes Library in HTML Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, primitive, shapes

Are there any libraries out there that provide some limited functionality for primitive shapes. I tried getting my feet wet with [EaselJS](http://www.easeljs.com/) and although it has some amazing properties, basic shapes is not one of them. Tests for inside a shape are carried out by pixel testing which is incredibly slow compared to for example ray testing.

I imagine the rectangle and the circle gets used the most, and I can create collision detection for the two of them, but things get more complicated with polygons. Are there any libraries out there for this? I know JQuery has one, but it seems like it is for HTML elements and not the canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [CAKE](http://glimr.rubyforge.org/cake/canvas.html#KeyboardTest)
or [processingjs](http://processingjs.org/). I'm not sure if these are particuarly suited to your needs, but they seem the most developed library's for canvas at the moment.